# How to resolve error when connecting to MS-SQL database via linux using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to external MS SQL database server from our Linux server using pyodbc and I am getting error.

Code:

```py
    import pyodbc
    server = 'XXXXXXXXX,port'
    database = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    username = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
    password = 'XXXXXXXX'
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()

    #Sample select query
    cursor.execute("SELECT @@version;")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    while row:
        print(row[0])
        row = cursor.fetchone()

    cnxn.close()
```

Error:

> cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "xxxxxxxxxx" requested by the login. The login failed. (4060) (SQLDriverConnect)')

I also tried reading multiple solutions and trying them for example:
putting password in brackets like --> password = '{XXXXXXXX}' becuase it had special characters.
Also tried giving server as --> server = 'tcp:XXXXXXXXX,port' nothing worked it all gives me same error.

Could you please guide me resolve this issue.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: The error is (partially) telling you the problem: *"Cannot open database "xxxxxxxxxx" requested by the login. The login failed."* Check the SQL Server's logs, that will give you the underlying error. If you don't understand that error, include that in your question. There could be many reasons for that error, and we can't give you an explicit reason without the real error.

Comment: Ask the team responsible for managing your server instance to give you a login and password that has the appropriate permissions.